Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylibpcap'"
I'm trying to use this Python libpcap library:
https://pypi.org/project/python-libpcap/
I have installed using:
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
pip3 install python-libpcap

but when I run the capture example code in script using sudo python3:
from pylibpcap.pcap import sniff

for plen, t, buf in sniff("my_interface", count=-1, promisc=1, out_file="pcap.pcap"):
    print("[+]: Payload len=", plen)
    print("[+]: Time", t)
    print("[+]: Payload", buf)

I get this error:
   from pylibpcap.pcap import sniff
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylibpcap'

How can I fix this/what's wrong?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.

I look up the manual for you quickly and tried to install the software on my own Mac to repeat the issue and help troubleshooting. But the installation was not even successful.
I took another look at their website and it appears to only support up to python 3.7. Based on your sys info, it looks like you have python 3.10 installed.
I suggested you to install python 3.6 or 3.7 then try this package again. Best luck!

Try this
pip3 install python-libpcap --user


Unfortunately it responded with (see end of comment) and I get the same error. Requirement already satisfied: python-libpcap in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.4.2) Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.29.23 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-libpcap) (3.0.10)

what is the output of pip3 show python-libpcap

pip3 show python-libpcap
Name: python-libpcap
Version: 0.4.2
Summary: Cython libpcap
Home-page: https://github.com/caizhengxin/python-libpcap
Author: JanKinCai
Author-email: jankincai12@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: Cython
Required-by:

I think you have multiple versions of python installed on your system which is causing this issue. Can you verify that!

Do you mean python and python3? (Python isn't my first language so I'm not totally sure how to fix this)

just type python and then press tab see how many python options are available
